# How to implement a custom peripheral driver for an embedded Linux project using STM32MP1?

Tags: embedded-linux, kernel-module, device-tree

I would like to undertake a low level approach to transferring data from an FPGA to the STM32MP1 processor, I'm currently using an FTDI USB device which is an extra IC consuming power on my battery power device.

I would initialise and read data from the QUADSPI peripheral on the STM32 in dual bank mode.

I have been reading into kernel modules to gain register level access however they all seem to stop at Hello World or best toggling GPIO pins. I can't find any solid documentation for what I'm trying to do.

What is the best way to initialise a peripheral that has no Linux driver written for it?

Comment: Find a similar driver(s) (i.e. same interface, similar functionality/capabilities) to use as a model/template for writing a "new" driver.